# Does removing a GitHub Repo also remove the Git Contribution History from the chart on your profile page?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

If I have a Repository called **my_project** and make a large number of commits over a few different weeks, my contribution history on my GitHub/GitLab (Should be true for both), the main page profile will look like the following:

[image: My_project commits over some time]

As above you can see varied commits in the contribution panel, dark colours for more and light green for less, with grey as no commits to the repo.

If I remove the repo does this all become grey? As in does the commit history for this graph on my landing page turn all those coloured cells from green to grey as there is no repo there any more associated with those commits.

The only reason I ask this, is because I have made a repo which I no longer need and was using to test out some python and git, however if I remove the repo I am worried that my profile will show that I have made no contributions for the past month on GitHub/GitLab, but I have, it's only I want to remove the project as it's no longer needed.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, it will be removed too.
However, if you don't want it you can make that repo as private so that publically it is not accessible to anyone and your contribution still shows up in history

Comment: Thank you - perfect response, will make a private repo instead to avoid losing commit history!

Comment: is this documented anywhere?